# Не могу разобраться с QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtablewidget

При запуске, открывается окно, но при нажатии кнопки все вылетает:

> self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1,' cellinfo')
>
> TypeError: setItem(self, int, int, QTableWidgetItem): **`argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'`**

```
import sys  # sys нужен для передачи argv в QApplication
import os   # Отсюда нам понадобятся методы для отображения содержимого директорий
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
#from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem

import design  # Это наш конвертированный файл дизайна


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна
        self.pushbutton_2.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)

    def browse_folder(self):
        #a = 'ttt'
        #self.tableWidget.SetItem(1,1,a)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1,' cellinfo')

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение


if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если мы запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
    main()  # то запускаем функцию main()
```

Answer (score 4):

> void QTableWidget::setItem(int row, int column, QTableWidgetItem *item)
>
> Устанавливает элемент для данной строки и столбца

```
import sys  
#import os  
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
#import design  


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): # , design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)  

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(3, 3)
        self.pushbutton_2 = QPushButton('Заполнить выбранные ячейки')
        self.pushbutton_2.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushbutton_2)

    def browse_folder(self):
        for index in self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes():
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setText(' cellinfo')
            self.tableWidget.setItem(index.row(), index.column(), item)       
        
#        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1,' cellinfo')

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp()  
    window.show()  
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]